# Why does this recursive function crash?

Tags: c++, crash, segmentation-fault

```
    int g(int n) {
        int x = g(n - 1);
        if (x > 0) {
            return x + 1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

My guess is it has to do with the first line of the function... But I'm not sure why that is the case.

Comment: Looks like you go into endless recursion. Typically you check for one or more base cases, if not the case then you make a recursive call.

Comment: g(n) is calling g(n-1) whatever the value of n, and never ending.

Answer (score 3):

If the function just said this:

```
int g(int n) {
    return g(n - 1);
}
```

then you would obviously not expect it to work, but instead keep recursing until you run out of stack space and the programme crashes. By putting the recursion before the exit condition in your function, you are basically doing exactly this.

You should rewrite the function so that it performs the exit test *before* calling `g()` again.

Comment: Ok, so the base case must be defined before the recursive call?

Comment: @user3019324: How would C++ ever reach it otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

If you run it through a debugger such as `gdb`, you should see that it never actually exits.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004004de in g (n=-240246) at test.c:10
```

`test.c:10` in my case is your `int x = g(n - 1);` line, which just keeps getting called over and over.

Answer (score 1):

Because the first line of the function calls exactly the same function, the 'return' will never get executed. Therefore it's an infinite loop, until it 'crashes'.

If we were to evaluate it:
`g(20)`: calls `g(19)`: calls `g(18)` and so on.

A recursive call often gets called at the end of the function, or at least after evaluation that makes sure the recursion is not infinite (such as in your example code).

Comment: So the 'if' statement will never even get looked at?  Does it crash on the first line?

Comment: Exactly, it never goes past the first line. Try to run a debugger with a breakpoint on the `if`: that will never hit. Running a debugger with a breakpoint on the `g(n-1)` call will continuously get hit.